# What is causing yarn-error.log and how does this affect my project?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, yarnpkg, e2e

I have recently installed yarn to my project to run cypress tests.

But I'm getting this **yarn-error.log** file, and I'm wondering what is generating that and how could this affect my project?
I do not understand the error that I get in it.

I already added this file to .gitignore
The file is very long so I'm just gonna post a screenshot of the part that seems to matter most.

Thanks in advance.[image]